# Which protocol Android uses to cast its screen to other devices like Chrome Cast

Tags: java, android, screencast

I want to develop a java application which acts like a Chrome Cast, so that I can stream my android screen to that application with wireless connection(s).

Answer (score 1):

Google's Chromecast use CASTV2 protocol. The following project implements client and server for nodejs and has some additional info on the protocol.

[thibauts/node-castv2](https://github.com/thibauts/node-castv2)